# How can I validate hebrew string input in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a textbox and I want to validate that the user enters only hebrew strings. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you doing the validation in winforms or asp.net?

Answer (score 5):

The obvious approach is to check the codepoints with TextBox.Text.ToCharArray().  Hebrew glyphs are codepoints 0x0580 through 0x05ff with supplementals 0xfb1d through 0xfb4f.  Plus the arabic digits.

Not being a native speaker, I would however assume that Latin characters can appear when spelling trade mark names, foreign words and acronyms.  Note the use of "RSS" in [this page](http://www.bdihot.co.il/category/%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94/).  Which put a pretty big hole in any attempt to verify the text.

Comment: this is also what my Israeli co-worker suggested when I showed him this question... :)

Comment: +1 for simplicity, but you are right, seems like it would be a difficult task to validate, but maybe the asker is looking for fairly specific strings.

Comment: One thing, and I still don't know what the original poster is trying to do but here's an idea:
 - Allow all strings
 - Since the Hebrew alphabet is finite, do a calculation on the %age of characters that are (numbers + Hebrew characters) against the total
 - If the total is below some %age, 70% or 80% or whatever, then post a message explaining why the message is rejected.

That might be simpler.

Comment: @chibacity: Ha! I wouldn't even know where to begin.  Perhaps some n-gram detection to determine what language the comments are in, and then post the error message in the detected language.  Because posting a Hebrew message isn't going to help the user -- if they spoke Hebrew they'd be able to read the instructions themselves. ;)

Comment: And that's a fair call.  Trust the user to know her own language.  She'll be a heckofalot smarter about it than I ever could be.  Starting at the age of 3, give or take.  Only validate a text entry when you *actually parse that text*.  And if you actually do, you'd never ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

avoid unicode chars in code

```
private const char FirstHebChar = (char)1488; //א
private const char LastHebChar = (char)1514; //ת
private static bool IsHebrew(this char c)
{
     return c >= FirstHebChar && c <= LastHebChar;
}
```

see http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2012/02/03/determine-if-char-is-hebrew-2/

Comment: -1  hans's unicode ranges are far more all encompassing. The little range you gave includes only letters and doesn't even include hebrew vowels.

Comment: Furthermore, it's more standard with unicode to use hex e.g. utf-16 like charmap uses so e.g.  in c# `char c = '\u05D0';` is clearer for unicode than saying `char c = 1488`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to go grab the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit @ http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/

Use the FilteredTextBox control (basically an extension of the textbox).

Keep in mind this only will prevent them from submitting the form if it has non-Hebrew strings.  It won't stop them from entering them in the text field.

But I imagine this is going to create a different problem.  You'll have to define what other characters are allowed, punctuation, numbers, etc.

What problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps we might be able to come up with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression that ensures the text is in a particular range.  You'll probably want to add the space character, as well as any R-to-L and L-R characters that are embedded.

Comment: The other problem of doing this and my suggestion is that what does he do when they hit an English word?  Think of a technical post where there is bound to be an English word in there somewhere.

Comment: @NinjaCat: Yes, this is a serious issue.  Real Hebrew speakers do toss in English words as needed.  Perhaps he could instead require that there be *some* Hebrew in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it with an ASP.NET web app, then you can use [the RegularExpressionValidator control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic6) with Unicode escape characters to create your RegEx match for valid strings.